# fullcalendar set fiscal calendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I currently have `fullcalendar` setup on my site and the problem I have is I have been looking for ways to set `fullcalendar` to follow a defined fiscal year instead of the calendar year. the `weekNumbers` follow the calendar year and this is not going to work with fiscal years (they start at October normally).

Is it possible to make `fullcalendar` recognize a fiscal year instead of the normal calendar year?

Or at the very least, can I make adjustments to how the `weekNumbers` are displayed?

**Example:**

```
Calendar Year = Week 31 = 2018-07-29 until 2018-08-04

Fiscal Year   = Week 44 = 2018-07-29 until 2018-08-04
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is really controlled by momentJS under the hood. The underlying calculation of the week number will not change...I would guess the only way to affect it would be a) implement a custom calendar in which years start in October - some people have done them as plugins for Islamic calendars etc (see https://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/), or b) whenever you get the week number from momentJS, run it through your own function and add the appropriate number of weeks on before using it to calculate anything - this maybe not be as simple as it sounds though, I'm not sure)

Comment: As an aside, interesting that the fiscal year starts in October, I'd never encountered that. In my part of the world by convention they almost always start in April (as that aligns with the taxman's fiscal year) or occasionally May. Although by law I believe a company can, if they wish, start their fiscal year anytime, few seem to do so.